# How to get index and create click event for dynamically created Button within ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, indexing, listbox

I am trying to create a note taking program, where each `Button` in `ListBox` is a "link" to Note(which is Window with textbox within), I save content of Note in a text file and Button's index important to get text correlated with that `Button`. I am 2 days looking for answer of simple question: just to get index of dynamically created `Button` and create click event for that `Button` and finally lost my patience and decided to ask. Closest thing I found was that I should create Click event in `ControlTemplate` for `Button` and I tried that but regardless I couldn't get index of button which is important for logic.

I have `ListBox`

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxOfButtons" Background="#404040" BorderThickness="0" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="50 -20 50 5"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
</ListBox>
```

And have "PlusButton" that adds dynamically created `Button`s to `ListBox`, that have ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="ButtonTemplate" x:Key="TemplateForButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

That is how I create them

```
 var btn = new Button();
 btn.Template = FindResource("TemplateForButton") as ControlTemplate;
 ListBoxOfButtons.Items.Add(btn);
```

What I want to do is create an Click event which has argument like index of Clicked(or selected) `Button` from `ListBox` and write logic for this, but I don't know neither how to get index, nor how to create Click event with index argument for dynamic `Button`.

Comment: You won't typically do it this way, but instead assign or bind the ListBox's ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of data item objects. The item class would expose an ICommand property to which the Button's Command property would be bound. The Button would be declared in the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl.

Comment: I didn't know lots of terms from your comment . I read about all of them, now what is not clear for me is "The Button would be declared in the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl.". Do you mean that I should create ItemsControl and within create DataTemplate that I'll use in ListBox via ItemTemplate property ?

Answer (score 1):

A Button can have a Name. If you are not already assigning a unique Name to each Button, you could do that and by checking the Name of the sender of the Click event, you have the unique identifier of the Button.

If for any reason you cannot do it this way, there's a slightly less elegant way where you can add a Tag to a Button. The Tag can be any object, and so you may wish to set the Tag of each Button to a unique string, for example. Again, in the Click event handler, check the Tag (you'll need to cast to the type of the object, for example, string) and you'll be able to get the unique Tag content.